# I'm Not A Racist Warrior!

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge, poetry

> Being a holy warrior is my pride
>   Yet will I never truly be a knight
>   For they say bad is my eyesight
>   Though I know that is not right
>
> It's just how I am meant to be
>   That half this earth I cannot see
>   But something really makes me happy
>   That an imaginary partner complements me
>
> I'm white, and I despise them who are black
>   But that does not make me a racist
>   And I can run very fast, and back
>   And those things make me such a beast
>
> Coincidentally, my boss lives next door
>   He's very lazy, yet amazingly prudent
>   His wife, I know, is a goddess of war
>   Well, I often helped her as a student
>
> Travelling is my favorite hobby
>   To Spain five times, to Italy four
>   In France everyone worships me
>   For among the black people I shall roar
>
> In a blink of an eye
>   This poem is a mess
>   But can you tell me who am I
>   And also my specific address?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is the

> White bishop in chess at f1

Being a holy warrior is my pride

> Bishop is a man of religion

For they say bad is my eyesight
Though I know that is not right

It's just how I am meant to be
That half this earth I cannot see

> It can only move on white squares of the chess board

But something really makes me happy
That an imaginary partner complements me

> I guess it is referring to the other bishop

I'm white, and I despise them who are black
But that does not make me a racist

> The white bishop is trying to capture black pieces

And I can run very fast, and back
And those things make me such a beast

> It can move as far diagonally as it wants

Coincidentally, my boss lives next door
He's very lazy, yet amazingly prudent

> The king is in the next square e1 and moves only one square at a time

His wife, I know, is a goddess of war
Well, I often helped her as a student

> The queen is of course the most powerful of the chess pieces.
> The "student" part is referring to the [Scholar's mate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scholar%27s_mate) with the queen and bishop.

Travelling is my favorite hobby
To Spain five times, to Italy four
In France everyone worships me
For among the black people I shall roar

> The only thing I can think of for the fifth stanza are chess openings:
> In [Spanish Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_Game) the bishop moves to b5
> In [Italian game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_Game) it moves to c4
> In [French game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Game) only the pawns move

Comment: Correct answer! However, can you explain the fifth stanza? And the term 'help her as a student'?

Comment: I added my guess for the 5th stanza but haven't figured out the student part.

Comment: "I can run very fast" probably refers to the German name for the piece.

Comment: All but one clue solved! "Very fast" just refers to the fact that it moves much faster than the knight. The last part, that it roars in France, is that it is the star attacking piece in the Greek Gift Sacrifice.

Answer (score 3):

It's the

> Sun

I guess, but yet I am not really sure about it.

Explanation:

Being a holy warrior is my pride, Yet will I never truly be a knight

> Many religions symbolize the Sun as the God, so holy warrior seems like that and then 'knight' is similar to night, so, for Sun there is no night.

It's just how I am meant to be
That half this earth I cannot see

> Nothing much to explain here.

But something really makes me happy
That an imaginary partner complements me

> The moon has none of it's own light, it just reflects the Sun's light to us that we say as moonlight. So, the moon is basically complimenting the sun's power of light.

I'm white, and I despise them who are black
But that does not make me a racist
And I can run very fast, and back
And those things make me such a beast

> Sunlight is white in color and it's speed is around 200 km/s.. and size is enormous, so it really is a beast.

Coincidentally, my boss lives next door
He's very lazy, yet amazingly prudent
His wife, I know, is a goddess of war
Well, I often helped her as a student

> I don't know alot about Greek and Egyptian Gods, so can't explain this one.

Travelling is my favorite hobby
To Spain five times, to Italy four
In France everyone worships me
For among the black people I shall roar

> We can relate black people to Africa, and it's known to everyone how hot the African deserts are.